# How to keep the Selected property true when clicked a not exist row in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

My ListView have to keep the `Selected` property true unless `Light` and `Time` value changed. (Because the ListView should remain in this state and Enabled should change to false.)

[image]

When I click outside ListView, the `Selected` property stays true. But, when I click a 'not exist' row of ListView, the `Selected` property doesn't stay true.

[image]

To solve this problem, I wrote a code in `ListView_Click` event, but `ListView_Click` event only occurs about rows with values.

What shoud I do?

Comment: You don't need to set Enabled to false. Set HideSelection to false, then handle ItemSelectionChanged and prevent the selection of other items, and set the colors accordingly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529743/how-to-keep-an-item-selected-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to suppress suppress the click behavior under those conditions is to make a custom `ListViewEx` class that overrides `WndProc` and performs a `HitTest` when the mouse is clicked. (You'll have to go to the designer file and swap out the `ListView` references of course.)

```
class ListViewEx : ListView
{
    const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            if (suppressClick())
            {
                m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    private bool suppressClick()
    {
        var hitTest = HitTest(PointToClient(MousePosition));
        if ((hitTest.Item == null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(hitTest.Item.Text))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: test result]

Comment: Jeez... When I said 'empty line, I meant 'not exist' line. I will edit the post by attaching a picture.

Comment: @IsakGo thx for adding the diagram. So it looks like you're still clicking inside the `ListView` but you're doing it below the last populated item, correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the selection locked to a specific item, and want to keep it highlighted no matter whether or not the form or the control has focus, do the following:

First, set `listView1.HideSelection = false`.

Then handle [ItemSelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.itemselectionchanged?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set the backcolor, forecolor and selected status accordingly:

```
int LockSelectionToIndex = 0; //Lock selection to index 0
private void listView1_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender,
    ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Item.Selected = (e.ItemIndex == LockSelectionToIndex);
    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
        e.Item.ForeColor = SystemColors.HighlightText;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Item.BackColor = SystemColors.Window;
        e.Item.ForeColor = SystemColors.WindowText;
    }
}
```